# Smarty Get variable from url is not correct ? (PRG)

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I'm trying to redirect user after he fills information about himself to same page with variable in url success = 1 but it seems that variable is empty or not correct. Form is displayed instead of message when URL is: http://example.com/contact.html?success=1. Can you help me please ? Thank you very much.

PHP:

```
function formSend(){
if($_POST['submit'] && $ok == 1)
  $out1 = "thank you very much";
  $_SESSION['thank_you'] = $out1;
  header("Location: $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?success=1");
  exit;
}else{
  showForm();
}
```

SMARTY:

```
{if $smarty.get.success == 1}
  {$smarty.session.thank_you} 
{else}
   {$showForm} {* Show form when address is http://example.com/contact.html?success=1 *}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Smarty is template engine. But you try insert to template logic of your application. This is very bad way.

You should check GET it your script and just set variables for Smarty.

Your template code can be:

```
{if $success == 1}
  Thank you very much
{else}
  {* There code of form *}
{/if}
```

Comment: what if I try {if strpos($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI, '?success=1')}

Comment: @user3105439 This can work. But this is incorrect method. In PHP script you programming logic of application. In template you programming how output information. I should't mixed it.